# Run javascript code which is in HTML if users click anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: I want to run this javascript code when users click below anchor.. but it's not working.. is there anybody who know the problem?]
the code is for copyfunction. when users click anchor, copyText should be save as clipboard

```html
 function myFunc {
    $('#link-button-1608115397633').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var copyText = "LASTCHANCE1";

          document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
             e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copyText);
              e.preventDefault();
         }, true);

           document.execCommand('copy');  
           alert('복사완료'); 
     })
};
```

Comment: What is the specific problem and  question here?

Comment: It's missing `()`: `function myFunc() {`. Also who is calling `myFunc` to add listener?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your function in onclick of anchor instead of href.

Follow as code:

```js
function myFunc() {
   let copyText = "LASTCHANCE1";
   
   document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
       e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', copyText);
        e.preventDefault();
   }, true);
   
   document.execCommand('copy');
   alert('복사완료');      
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="myFunc();return false;" >Execute Func</a>
```